# Reverse dictionary comprehension method not working

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, comparison, dictionary-comprehension

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
Prelim_firmpan = {'06059C0127J': 'J','06059C0090J': 'J','06059C0288K': 'K',
'06059C0190J': 'J','06059C0436J': 'J','06059C0158J': 'J','06059C0229K': 'K',
'06059C0227K': 'K'}

NFHL_firmpan = {'06059C0127J': 'J','06059C0090J': 'J','06059C0319J': 'J',
'06059C0313J': 'J','06059C0329J': 'J','06059C0258J': 'J','06059C0444J': 'J'}
```

I want to find the number of difference between these two dictionaries. I have a method to find the number of similar files. As you can see, there are 2 shared files between these two dictionaries; `'06059C0127J': 'J'` and `'06059C0090J': 'J'`. The following gives that results:

```
shared = {k: Prelim_firmpan[k] for k in Prelim_firmpan if k in NFHL_firmpan and Prelim_firmpan[k] == NFHL_firmpan[k]}
num_shared = len(shared)
print(num)
```

Now I want to do something similar to get the number of items from `Prelim_firmpan` that are **not in** `NFHL_firmpan`. The following only returns an empty set. Any suggestions on making this work?

```
unshared = {k: Prelim_firmpan[k] for k in Prelim_firmpan if k in NFHL_firmpan and Prelim_firmpan[k] != NFHL_firmpan[k]}
num_unshared = len(unshared)
print(unshared)
>>>0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition `if k in NFHL_firmpan and Prelim_firmpan[k] != NFHL_firmpan[k]` will never be True.
Why not use `if k not in NFHL_firmpan`?

```
unshared = {k: Prelim_firmpan[k] for k in Prelim_firmpan if k not in NFHL_firmpan}
num_unshared = len(unshared)
print(unshared)
#{'06059C0288K': 'K', '06059C0190J': 'J', '06059C0436J': 'J', '06059C0158J': 'J', '06059C0229K': 'K', '06059C0227K': 'K'}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked great. I need to test the numbers out because the actually dictionaries have hundreds of items. But this seems correct, thanks!